# Show that all norm in $\mathbb{R}$ is of the form $\vert\vert x\vert\vert=a\cdot\vert x\vert$

Tags: metric-spaces

Show that all norm $\vert\vert .\vert\vert$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is of the form $\vert\vert x\vert\vert=a\cdot\vert x\vert$, where $a>0$ is a constant and $\vert x\vert$ is  the absolute value of $x$.

Is obvious that all norm in $\mathbb{R}$ is of the form $a\vert x\vert$, but how I can formalized this?? I think I should define the function $f(x)=\vert\vert x\vert\vert-a\cdot\vert x\vert$, and maybe think  in inner product to show that $f(x)\equiv 0$. Any hint pls!

Comment: Note that you can assign any positive number to be the norm of $x=1$, say $\|1\| = a > 0$. Now, note that any norm must satisfy the property $\|cx\| = |c|\|x\|$ for all real $x$ and $c$. What happens when you apply this condition to $x=1$?

Comment: It is a one-liner, but it is not completely obvious. Forget about inner products for a moment. Given a norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$, how would you compute $a$? What could you then conclude about $\Vert x \Vert$ from the norm-axiom $\Vert \alpha \cdot x \Vert = |a| \cdot \Vert x \Vert$?

Comment: Suppose that $N$ is a norm in $\Bbb R$. Recall then that $N(ax)=|a|N(x)$ for every $x$ and thus $N(a1)=|a|N(1)$.