# Every norm in $\mathbb{R}$ has the form $||x||=a|x|$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

How can I prove the following?

Every norm in $\mathbb{R}$ has the form $||x||=a|x|$ where $a>0$ and $|x|$ is the absolute value of $x$. Conclude that every norm in $\mathbb{R}$ comes from a inner product.

First I think in prove by contradiction, but I don't know how to express that $||x||$ doesn't has the form $a|x|$, so maybe that's not the way.

I'm just starting to study metric spaces, and I really don't know how to solve this. If there is some hint to guide me I'll appreciate it.

Comment: Use that $x=x\cdot 1$ and the property $\|x\cdot y\|=|x|\cdot\|y\|$.

Comment: Similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1504375/show-that-all-norm-in-mathbbr-is-of-the-form-vert-vert-x-vert-vert-a-cdot?rq=1, although it doesn't have an accepted answer so I can't mark dupe

Comment: @cactus simple like that, haha.
Thank you!

Comment: I've answered the question

Comment: Now select it as the right answer, after you finish showing that $a>0$, and that the norm comes from an inner product.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $a=||1||>0$. So $||x||=||1\cdot x||=||1|| \,|x|=a|x|$.

Comment: Hello Mateus! Quick question: Why does $\|1 \cdot x\|=\|1\||x|$ ? When I first wrote this equality, i thought that $\|1 \cdot x\|=\|1\|\|x\|$

Comment: I thought that $1$ should be inside the absolute value, since it is the scalar quantity in question. However, since $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $x$ is also a scalar quantity... is that why $x$ is inside an absolute value? Also, why that implies that every norm in $\mathbb{R}$ comes from an inner product? Cheers from another brazilian!

Comment: Hi, Lucas!
Basically, any norm is "multiplicative", I mean, if $\lambda$ is a scalar, so 
$||\lambda\cdot  x||=| \lambda |\cdot ||x||$.
Here, $| \cdot |$ denotes the absolute value of the scalar $\lambda$.

The key is to "change" the roles. Consider $x$ as the scalar multiplying the number $1$ (since we are working in $\Bbb{R}$, every element is a scalar itself).

Comment: I got it, thanks! The only part I still cannot understand is how the proposition implies that every norm in $\mathbb{R}$ comes from an inner product. Can you clarify that? Please